# ion-select update model on value selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a login form, in which I require you to select the provider from a drop down before logging in.
If a user selects a value but does not click okay, the value does not get set.
I don't want to enforce the user to click that

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="loginProviderChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="provider" name="provider" placeholder="Select Type" >
    <ion-select-option value="StripeConnect" >
      StripeConnect
    </ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Google">
      Google
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I tried to fix this by plugging into the ionChange event, however it's not triggered

```
loginProviderChanged(provider: string) {
  this.provider = provider;
}
```

How can I update the model on select?

Comment: Have you considered using an action-sheet or popover interface for your `<ion-select>`? These options will trigger a change event when a selection is made without needing to click "okay" https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#interfaces

Comment: @Wesley I just took a look at them. I don't really like there native styles.

Comment: Your call, it's your app. If this is a mobile app I'd use the action sheet interface and call it a day as that's the kind of native control users would expect anyway. Alternatively you could use a modal instead or just customize the styles of the popover to get the look you want.